# Powershell get-help not returning proper help syntax

Tags: powershell

When typing `get-help ls` from the file system in Powershell 4.0 or Powershell 5.0 on Windows 7, I get:

```
SYNTAX
Get-ChildItem [[-Path] <String[]>] [[-Filter] <String>] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Force] [-Include <String[]>] [-Name] [-Recurse] 
[-UseTransaction [<SwitchParameter>]] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-ChildItem [[-Filter] <String>] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Force] [-Include <String[]>] [-Name] [-Recurse] -LiteralPath <String[]> 
[-UseTransaction [<SwitchParameter>]] [<CommonParameters>]
```

I am expecting to see another entry that includes information on the -Attributes parameter.

Trying to force it, with `get-help ls -Path C:` gives me the same result.

Trying again to force it, with `get-help ls -Parameter Attributes` gives the following error

```
get-help : No parameter matches criteria Attributes.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-help ls -Parameter Attributes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Manageme...CommandHelpInfo:ProviderCommandHelpInfo) [Get-Help], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoParmsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

However, I can still run queries such as `ls -Attributes d` that return the appropriate result. In this case, a list of all directories in the current directory.

I have tried reinstalling WMF. I have tried reinstalling the help documentation with `Update-Help -force`. I am completely stumped here.

Comment: What version of PowerShell?

Comment: Tried with both PowerShell 4.0 and 5.0. That is I installed up to WMF 5.0, then uninstalled the patch and tried it with PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behavior on 4.0 nor on 5.0 on Windows 10. Since the only installable WMF versions out right now are previews, it's possible that this is an issue with one of those. If others can confirm it might be good report this.

Comment: Have you tried running `Update-Help`? The `-Attributes` parameter shows up in PowerShell v3.0 and not v2.0 if you did an upgrade from v2.0 to v4.0 it might be using the old help file?

Comment: I have run Update-Help, including using it with the -force option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success! Here is what I did to get it to work.

Ran `Save-Help` to save a local copy of the help files on disk.

Then ran `Update-Help -SourcePath filePath` to use those downloaded files to update help.

It does not make any sense why `Update-Help -force` was not working. I can only guess that perhaps my company's system is setup to use a local copy of the help files, but manually downloading the files forces it to use Microsoft's.

Interestingly enough, running `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Path $null` as discussed in the help files does *not* give information about the Get-ChildItem cmdlet in all drives. I had to write `get-help ls -Path Registry::hklm:\`